# Best way to mock out external web services while testing a web application in development

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, integration-testing

Currently I am working on an application which depends on a lot of external web services. A few of them are *authorize.net* and *chargify*.

When testing(manual testing) things other than the integration with these web services, I replace these web service dependencies with fake versions of them which don't really do anything. The way I am doing it as of now, is by using the following line of code in the structure map registry class:

```
    For<IChargifyService>().Use<MockChargifyService>(); //uncomment this line to use a mock chargify service
```

I have similar lines in the registry for other fake services. I comment them out while deploying so that the real services are used in production. The real and fake service implementations are present in the `Infrastructure` assembly.

The problem with this approach is that I have to *remember* to uncomment the lines before deploying. I know there is a way to do this using Structure Xml Config, But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. Would creating a `Mock Infrastructure` assembly be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways I can think of:

1) You can create a separate assembly, as you suggested, that contains all of your mock implementations. You would also include a Registry in that assembly which sets the mock implementations as the defaults. The Registry in your main assembly would have to do a Scan that to optionally load your mock assembly - something like:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.TheCallingAssembly();
    x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
    x.LookForRegistries();
});
```

2) Another option is to create a Profile for your mocks:

```
Profile("Test", x =>
{
    x.For<IChargifyService>().Use<MockChargifyService>();
    // etc.
});
```

Then somewhere in your application you would call:

```
ObjectFactory.Profile = "Test";
```

based on some environmental condition that indicates you are in test mode.

Comment: Thanks :) I am thinking of going with the profile option, it looks like the most flexible option.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/) ([Getting Started](http://www.soapui.org/gettingstarted/mocking.html)).